# Typescript: Reactive forms patchValue not working with private properties and getters/setters

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using an Angular/.net application with .net6.0 framework, with Angular: 13.1.2, Node: 16.13.1 and EMCAScript 5.

I have the following person class in typescript.

```
export class Person {

  private _name: string = '';
    
  constructor() {
  }

  public get name(): string {
    return this._name;
  }

  public set name(value: string) {
    this._name = value;
  }
}
```

While compiling the following person.model.js file is generated.
But I'm under the impression the Object.defineProperties doesn't work.

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var Person = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Person() {
        this._name = '';
    }
    Object.defineProperty(Person.prototype, "name", {
        get: function () {
            return this._name;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            this._name = value;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    return Person;
}());
exports.Person = Person;
//# sourceMappingURL=person.model.js.map
```

Whenever I try to update my Reactive form using an object no data is updated.
While I'm debugging I only notice the '_name' property in the 'Object.Keys' array.

```
 this.personForm.get('person')?.patchValue(person);
```

Reactive form is defined the following way.

```
    return formBuilder.group({
      person: formBuilder.group({
        name: [
          '',
          [
            Validators.required
          ]
        ]
      })
    });
```

Whenever I update my class with 'Object.DefineProperty' the above code updating the Reactive form seems to work without problems. Also the 'Name' property seems to have been added to the 'Object.Keys' array.

```
export class Person {

  private _name: string = '';
    
  constructor() {
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', {
      set: function (value: string) {
        this._name = value;
      },
      get: function () {
        return this._name;
      },
      enumerable: true
    })
  }
}
```

Do I need to add the Object.defineProperties in the .ts file or is my application not using the generated .js files ?

EDIT:

Component

```
export class PersonComponent implements OnInit {

  personForm!: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private _fb: FormBuilder) {}

  private CreateFormGroup(formBuilder: FormBuilder): FormGroup {
    return formBuilder.group({
      person: formBuilder.group({
        name: [
          '',
          [
            Validators.required
          ]
        ]
      })
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.personForm = this.CreateFormGroup(this._fb);
  }

  setPerson(person: Person) {
    if (person != undefined) {
      this.personForm.get('person')?.patchValue(person);
    }
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<mat-card class="mat-elevation-z10">
  <mat-card-title>Person</mat-card-title>
  <mat-card-content>
    <form [formGroup]="personForm">
      <div formGroupName="person">
        <mat-form-field class="person-name">
          <input id="name" matInput aria-label="name" type="text" formControlName="name" autofocus required />
          <mat-placeholder class="placeholder">name</mat-placeholder>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <br />
    </form>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
<app-person-selection (personEvent)="setPerson($event)"></app-person-selection>
```

Comment: Hello @Mathias Cloet and Welcome to Stackoverflow, can you share with us in which component lifecycle did you define lines ? (i mean the initialization of your reactive form and also the patchValue line), to be sure that you defined your lines in its correct places

Comment: @sohaiebazaiez I've added the component and HTML code to the original message. The 'setPerson' method gets called when I doubleclick on an entry in the app-person-selection grid.

Comment: thank you for your clean code, 
i just reproduced your code here in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xr3eqz?file=src/app/app.component.ts) you can also check my two comments there in the method `createPerson(..)` to test both cases , 
i just want to know something: are you sure that the output of `app-person-selection`: `(personEvent)=".."` returns the correct type of the object `$event`? if yes , you should in that case insure it to be of type "any" instead of "Person", i guess typescript is not taking the right instance type

Comment: Thx for the reply, when passing an object of type 'any' the patchValue works as I expect. However I'm passing a 'Person' object as parameter check the following two examples in stackblitz. [Working as expected](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3tcvzm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) [Does nothing](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-67ccha?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) The difference between the two examples is in 'Person.ts'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript does transpiles the getter/setter into an equivalent `Object.defineProperty` syntax.

But if you carefully look at the transpiled code, you will observe that the `name` property is defined on `Person.prototype` i.e on function's prototype, and not on the function itself.

```
// Transpiled code with v3.9.7
var Person = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Person() {
        this._name = '';
    }
    Object.defineProperty(Person.prototype, "name", {  // <----
        get: function () {
            return this._name;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            this._name = value;
        },
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: true
    });
    return Person;
}());
```

Whereas in the 2nd scenario, wherein you manually define `Object.defineProperty`, you are passing 1st argument as `this`, and not Person.prototype.

```
// Transpiled code with v3.9.7
var Person = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Person() {
        this._name = '';
        Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', {  // <----
            set: function (value) {
                this._name = value;
            },
            get: function () {
                return this._name;
            },
            enumerable: true
        });
    }
    return Person;
}());
```

This is the reason why `name` property is not visible within `Object.keys` in 1st scenario (getter/setter), but is visible in the 2nd scenario. And for the same reason the `patchValue` doesn't work as `name` is not an object's own enumerable property.

Comment: @MathiasCloet What's the rationale behind using private `name` property? Can't we simply make use of public property, that will resolve the issue. If you want setter for Validation purpose, we can always have validators with reactive forms.

Comment: Rationale for the private property was reserved for validations. But I can resort to validators in reactive forms and backend validation. When changing properties from private to public the problem is indeed fixed.